# Как обрезать/вывести все символы в блоке по клику на кнопку "свернуть/подробнее"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу обрезать до 70 символов к примеру чтобы в конце встало многоточие, пробовал применять инструкции которые нашел в интернете. Но что то не заработало, в итоге оставил только то, что может пригодиться (код ниже)

```js
  $(".parent .text").each(function() {
     var lenth = $(this).html().substring(0, 170);
  $(this).html(lenth);
    // а как нормально обрезать, чтобы потом вернуть, не знаю
  });


  $(".parent .rmore").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".parent").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("act");
    if ($(this).hasClass("act")) {
      $(this).html("cвернуть");
    } else {
      $(this).html("подробнее...");
    }
  });
```

```css
.rmore {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #F8BBD0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  transition: 700ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="text-justify">

      Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный
      эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия. Не следует, однако забывать, что сложившаяся
      структура организации способствует подготовки и реализации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="rmore">подробнее...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="text-justify">

      Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный
      эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия. Не следует, однако забывать, что сложившаяся
      структура организации способствует подготовки и реализации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="rmore">подробнее...</div>
</div>
```

варианты на css не предлагать

Comment: $(this).html().substr(0,70);

Comment: вставил вот так, но не заработало:`$(".parent .text").each(function() {
$(this).html().substr(0,70);`

Comment: да нет, привяжите к переменной:

Comment: в общем сделал, читайте вопросы с изменениями, но это только обрезанный текст, но обратно его уже не вернуть как я понял

Comment: $(".parent .text").each(function() { var newString = $(this).html().substr(0,70) + "...";

Comment: Подправил комментарий)) Вместо точки - знак "+". А с переменной newString делайте, что хотите. Вместо нее заносите обрезанные строки в массив, а затем можете выводить его значения в нужном месте программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  $(function() {
    $(".parent .text p").each(function() {
      $(this).data('full', $(this).html());
      $(this).html($(this).html().substr(0, 70));

    });


    $(".parent .rmore").click(function() {
      $(this).parents(".parent").toggleClass("active");
      $(this).toggleClass("act");

      if ($(this).is(".act")) {
        $(this).html("cвернуть");
        $(this).siblings('.text').find('p').html($(this).siblings('.text').find('p').data('full'));
      } else {
        $(this).html("подробнее...");
        $(this).siblings('.text').find('p').html($(this).siblings('.text').find('p').html().substr(0, 70));
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
  .rmore {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #F8BBD0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .parent {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #F1F1F1;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 15px;
    transition: 700ms;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="text-justify">
      Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный
      эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия. Не следует, однако забывать, что сложившаяся
      структура организации способствует подготовки и реализации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rmore">подробнее...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="text-justify">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat possimus voluptas officiis est odio porro corporis reiciendis consequuntur laboriosam ad quae numquam impedit, a animi, consectetur inventore minus eveniet nam!
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="rmore">подробнее...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а есть ли функция которая считает не количество символов а количество строк?? потому что может быть так что перенос строки расставлен 20 раз но всего в блоке 50 символов а моет быть что переносов строк вообще нет, а символов 70, высота блока при этом будет разная, Если нет, то ладно оставлю так, просто буду контент под гонять под нормальный вид

Comment: и еще нет ли способо вместо того чтобы добавлять data, добавлять класс, потому что как вы заметили в в css есть свойство transition, так вот оно при сворачивании и разворачивании не применяется...